# XML and XSL transformation categories not shown

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a Problem and tried it so many times but I cannot solve it. Maybe I have overseen something very simple. I am a very beginner in doing XML and XSL.

This is my XML-Code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tapete>
        <category>
        <name>MOBILE ICONS</name>
            <icon>
                <assetid>001</assetid>
                <title>car_setup</title> 
            </icon>
        </category>
        
        <category>
        <name>HUMAN ICONS</name>
            <icon>
                <assetid>001</assetid>
                <title>car_setup</title>
            </icon>
        </category>
</tapete>
```

This is my XSL-Code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
    <xsl:for-each select="tapete/category">
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h2>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="tapete/category/icon">
    <xsl:value-of select="assetid"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now I have the Problem that for each category just one assetid is shown.
I would be so grateful if anybody can help me to solve this Problem.

Thank you in Advance.
Natalie

Comment: Please post your XML, XSLT and the expected result **as code**, not pictures, within your question.

Comment: I posted both codes.

Comment: so as assetid appear only once in you xml so in output its coming is right what your expectation?

Comment: I still don't see the expected result. Also it is not true that *"for each category just one assetid is shown"*. Your code lists all the categories first; then it lists all the assets (and their associated titles) in a separate, unrelated, list.

Comment: I already solved it. But thank you for your help:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what xsl:value-of in XSLT 1.0 does. If you select a set of nodes, it displays the first. In XSLT 2.0, it will display all the selected nodes, so either move to XSLT 2.0, or process the nodes individually using a nested xsl:for-each.